# How to set the default value for radio buttons in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I need to make a system to change the total price by number of tickets selected. I created some radio buttons to choose the number of ticket. The ploblem is that the default value is unset and the result is null on loading.

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="people" value="1" checked="checked"><label>1</label>
<input type="radio" ng-model="people" value="2"><label>2</label>
<input type="radio" ng-model="people" value="3"><label>3</label>
<ul>
  <li>{{10*people}}€</li>
  <li>{{8*people}}€</li>
  <li>{{30*people}}€</li>
</ul>
```

[Please see my jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Nuw9R/)

Comment: what default value you want to set

Comment: side note for anyone getting here from using {{$index}} for value, your model needs to stringify the initial value '1'.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Set a default value for `people` with [ngInit](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInit)

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-init="people=1" />
        <input type="radio" ng-model="people" value="1"><label>1</label>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="people" value="2"><label>2</label>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="people" value="3"><label>3</label>
    <ul>
        <li>{{10*people}}€</li>
        <li>{{8*people}}€</li>
        <li>{{30*people}}€</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/P3ctY/)

Comment: you can also do so inside the controller by setting scope.people=1, which is the recommended way described in http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInit

Comment: @Arun, What if values have characters instead of digit. Then how would be the code for `ng-init` look like?

Comment: @MrSuS `people='chars'`

Comment: using `ng-init` is bad practice. this approach is only effecitive for a Form being populated for the 1st time. If you have values and assigned them to model binders, ng-init will overwrite your values.

Comment: what if I used `ng-value` and for default radio I want to use `ng-value = ""` because that model I use to filter on a list later on, and the default filter shouldn't filter on anything, hence empty string?

Comment: better to initialize your model in the controller with your default value and in the html use ng-checked="true" ... while working on angular try not to misuse ng-init

Answer (score 25):

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="myCntrl">    
        <input type="radio" ng-model="people" value="1"/><label>1</label>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="people" value="2"/><label>2</label>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="people" value="3"/><label>3</label>
</div>
<script>
    function myCntrl($scope){
        $scope.people=1;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 15):

why not just `ng-checked="true"`

Comment: Because it would check the radio button visually, but would not set the value of "people" like if u had click on the radio button through a browser.

Comment: The answers section is not a good place for questions.  This would be better in comments on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Angular 2 this is how we can set the default value for radio button:

HTML:

```
<label class="form-check-label">
          <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="gender" 
          [(ngModel)]="gender" id="optionsRadios1" value="male">
          Male
</label>
```

In the Component Class set the value of 'gender' variable equal to the value of 
  radio button:

```
gender = 'male';
```

Answer (score -6):

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"<%=rs.getString(6).equals("male") ? "checked='checked'": "" %>: "checked='checked'" %> >Male
               <%=rs.getString(6).equals("male") ? "checked='checked'": "" %>
```