# How to make a radio button checked by default

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have 3 radio buttons - All,Pass,Fail. I want all to be checked by default and value value of that radio button in ng-model.

How can I achieve this?

If I am using ng-checked = "true" it checked but I am not getting the value of selected radio that is All in my model variable .

If i use checked="checked" or checked this also not giving me tha value in model 
variable.

```
input type="radio" value="all" ng-checked="true" ng-model="model"
```

On load of the page when I access $scope.model in my controller I want value as all.

Any help appricated

Comment: Fiddle your code and share

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833692/how-to-set-the-default-value-for-radio-buttons-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SantoshPandu/m22ayLk0/1/)

HTML

```
<section ng-app="app">
     <h2 ng-controller="controller">
                <input type="radio"  value="1" ng-model="ChkBox"/> Checkbox 1
                <input type="radio" value="2" ng-model="ChkBox"/> Checkbox 2
            </h2>
</section>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
function controller($scope) {
    $scope.ChkBox = '1';   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-app>
<div ng-init="x=1" />
<input type="radio" ng-model="x" value="1">1 <br/>
<input type="radio" ng-model="x" value="2">2 <br/>
<div>{{x}}</div>
</div>
```