# angularjs 1.x radio doesn't set null value

Tags: angularjs, forms

I have an angular filter directive with 3 radio buttons.
The values are null, true, false. But model doesn't save null value when I click on null button. How I can achieve it? I need model=null before click on related button.

```
$scope.items = [
    {val: null, text: 'null'},
    {val: true, text: 'true'},
    {val: false, text: 'false'}
  ];
```

Here is a demo http://plnkr.co/edit/LlAiKrpadcCYGXI2IFsR?p=preview

Thanks

Comment: Your demo works ...

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant I'm sorry, I've updated question. I have to have default value null. thank you

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/rAsnCmJxKn654jy54Ekm?p=preview just have to write $scope.model = { value: null };

Comment: thank you @PierreEmmanuelLallemant is there any way to do it through templates?

Comment: Seems to be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833692/how-to-set-the-default-value-for-radio-buttons-in-angularjs or at least it could guide you to an answer. Use ng-init that async loads the default value.

Comment: @AndrewAdam they use ng-init value any case, but I want to use null value only for default value

Comment: in the proposed answer there the ng-init sets the default value as you expect if I am not mistaken. What else do you need? I mean the question's title is 'How to set the default value for radio buttons in AngularJS?' and was viewed over 100k times with four answers. I also think this will resolve your issue (either the accepted answer or the one with second most upvotes)

Comment: @AndrewAdam obviously, default value means the value which used in case when the value is not defined. ng-init sets the value every time. my model may have a value, so I want to keep it and display it instead of rendering default value.

Comment: Then you can easily add a condition to your ng-init which only loads the default value when the page loads other than that it keeps the user's input value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set **`data-ng-value="radio.text"`** in the directive

```
  <input class="radio_simple_real" type="radio"
         data-ng-model="$parent.model"
         data-ng-value="radio.text">
```

[`PLUNKER DEMO`](http://plnkr.co/edit/RI5ScD5kmGXJIifmYjiX?p=preview)

Comment: I need null value, instead of 'null'

Comment: what do you mean by null value? null does not have a value

Comment: null is the null. Please don't waste your time If you don't know javascript. btw, typeof null is 'object'

Comment: Lol. Ok buddy I don't know JavaScript 

Comment: lol, I write 'null' in text field just for example. Why did you use it as 'null' value? I need JSON with the following value `{"field": null` and not `{"field": "null"}`